# Button in java jframe will not resize?

Tags: java, swing

I started java programming yesterday, and have developed this. I have run into a problem, as the button will not resize. Please help if you can and thank you in advance.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

class BgPanel extends JPanel {
Image bg = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\********\\Pictures\\tiger.jpg").getImage();
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
     }
}

public class FrameTestBase extends JFrame {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    JPanel bgPanel = new BgPanel();
    bgPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    final FrameTestBase t = new FrameTestBase();
    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\********\\Pictures\\gear-icon.png");
    t.setLayout(null);
    t.setIconImage(img.getImage());
    t.setTitle("Login");
    t.setSize(600,600);
    t.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    t.setContentPane(bgPanel);
    t.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    t.setVisible(true);

    JButton registerButton = new JButton("register");
    registerButton.setBounds(80, 80, 80, 80);
    t.add(registerButton);
         }
     }
```

Comment: You should do `t.setVisisble(true)` as the very last thing.  This is because once the frame is visible, it becomes trickier to make changes to the the size/position/layout of the GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have run into a problem, as the button will not resize. Please help
>   if you can and thank you in advance.

```
 bgPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
 // --------- your other code
 t.setLayout(null);
 //--------------- your other code
 t.setContentPane(bgPanel); // you are setting bgPanel which has BorderLayout
 JButton registerButton = new JButton("register");
 registerButton.setBounds(80, 80, 80, 80);
 t.add(registerButton); // t is the JFrame, your main window
```

Any `JFrame.add(component)` will essentially add your component to the content pane of the JFrame.  After setting layout to `null` you have added the `bgPanel` as content pane to the JFrame, which has BorderLayout as its layout manager. Adding your button to the content pane i.e.,`bgPanel` will add your `registerButton` with `BorderLayout.Center` constraint. That is why this button is expanding to the size of the screen.

As you are so eager to see an output do the following:

```
    // registerButton.setBounds(80, 80, 80, 80); comment out this line
    registerButton.setPreferedSize(new Dimension(80, 80));
    t.add(registerButton, BorderLayout.PAGE_START)
```

**Now, About using NULL Layout:**

In your own example you have lost to find the reason why the Button is expanding to the window size. In near future you will see that one of your component has head but lost its tail by going outside of the window border. You will see that one of your component is going to jump over the other without no reason. You will see that you have changed a position of component with relative to another component, but it will make relation with other component. Well you will be able to find the issues wasting lost of time and get fixed by setting `xxxSize`, `setLocation`, `setBounds` etc but....

*people can be rich in money, they can't be rich in time.*

Start learning LayoutManager: [Lesson: Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: Thank you, I have realised that this is the wrong way to go, and have started a new script following all advice here.

Comment: @DIOS: It appears you've already been given links to using the layout managers. Looks like it's time to actually read them. 1+ to Sage's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `registerButton.setSize(new Dimension(width, height))` instead of `setBounds`.
Remember to replace `width` and `height` for new values

And I forget to say the same thing guys are telling you:

**Don't use null layout.**

The sooner you learn, the better.
Layouts are not difficult, they're actually easy.

Comment: I have tried this and it still expands to the size of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't use a null layout!!!**

Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. And don't forget to follow Mike's suggestion.

Comment: Thank you. I have solved this by re-inventing my code. I can use null layout by adding co-ordinates.

Comment: @DIOS, why do you bother to ask a question when you don't listen to the solution? Using a null layout is the wrong approach for too many reasons to list here.

Comment: I do listen and care about peoples comments, and have scraped this script and started a new one using cardlayout due to your advice.